# Compute a lebesgue integration

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$, show that the function $(x,y) \rightarrow e^{-\alpha xy} \sin x$ is lebesgue integrable on $(0,\infty)\times (1,\infty)$ and compute its two iterated integrals and $\int^\infty_0 e^{-\alpha x} \dfrac {\sin x}{x} \, dx$

It's very complicated when I compute the iterated integrals directly. This problem appears in real analysis book, so I think the theorems such as Fubini theorem may make them easier. But I don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

We have by Tonelli's theorem,

$$\iint_{(0,\infty) \times (1,\infty)} |e^{-\alpha xy} \sin x| \, d(x,y) = \int_0^\infty \int_1^{\infty} |e^{-\alpha xy} \sin x | \, dy \, dx = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin x|}{x} e^{-\alpha x} \, dx \le \frac1{\alpha} \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x} \, dx < \infty$$

(using $|\sin x| \le x$)

Hence $(x,y) \mapsto e^{-\alpha xy} \sin x \in L^1$. Thus, by Fubini's theorem, the iterated integrals are equal. Now, integrating by parts,

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha xy} \sin x \, dx = \frac{1}{1 + (\alpha y)^2 }$$

Hence,

$$\int_1^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha xy} \sin x \, dx \, dy = \frac1{\alpha} (\pi/2 - \tan^{-1} \alpha)$$

On the other hand,

$$\int_0^\infty \int_1^\infty e^{-\alpha xy} \sin x \, dx \, dy = \frac1{\alpha} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{x} \sin x \, dx$$

Therefore,

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{- \alpha x}}{x} \sin x \, dx = \frac{\pi}2 - \tan^{-1} \alpha$$